# BeautifulSoup is right there in Canopy, but could not be imported

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nlp

Installed BeautifulSoup on MacOS, 
it could be imported from system terminal:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
```

But when I try to import in Canopy, it shows error of no module.

```
In [68]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-9144e80cd349> in <module>()
----> 1 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

However, after I switched to Canopy Terminal, check the pip list and re-install, it seems the module is already there, so how couldn't I import it in Canopy?

```
(Canopy 64bit) MacBook-Pro:~ $ pip install beautifulsoup4
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 in      ./Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.5.1-py2.7.egg

(Canopy 64bit) MacBook-Pro:~ $ pip list
appinst (2.1.5)
appnope (0.1.0)
apptools (4.4.0)
atom (0.3.10)
backports-abc (0.4)
beautifulsoup4 (4.5.1)
Canopy (1.5.5)
CanopyDataImport-addon (0.0.1)
```

My python version is 2.7:

```
MacBook-Pro:~$ python
Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.9 | 64-bit | (default, Jun 30 2015, 19:41:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.6)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Comment: You have different versions of python installed,  the python you see when you run *python* in bash  has nothing to do with Canopy.

Comment: Yes, I know this problem However, as I mentioned above, I went to the Canopy Terminal and tried to install there, it said "Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): beautifulsoup4 ..."